# User can log in without supplying password on localhost

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a Asp.net web site built on C# with Forms Authentication. We use an Active Directory to authenticate the users, and everything works fine. But today we realized that it's possible to login to any account by just entering the username and click Login, without supplying any password! This is only happening on the development environment running on localhost (thank god!), but I don't like it...

I've never seen this behaviour before, and would really like someone to explain how this could happen. Is this a developer feature built by Microsoft? Or did someone at my office make a backdoor without telling the rest? I will investigate this last option further, but until then - have anyone encountered this before?

Big thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is where the authentication returns true for every username I throw at it - with a blank password. Other passwords return false.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   result = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

`PrincipalContext` is the default from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: did you develop your own membership/role provider?

Comment: Are `username` and `password` `null` when you call `ValidateCredentials` by any chance? If that were the case, the method would auth using the default user credentials (probably of the user running IIS).

Comment: @hangy: Good thinking, but it's an empty string (""), not null

Comment: @Shoban: yes, it inherits System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider and we override every method with NotImplementedException, except for ValidateUser

Comment: @Niklas you might want to attach w3p process and run your provider in debug mode and see what happens exactly in your provider.

Comment: You're using AD, but you're not using windows authentication, is that right?  Is your dev box in the same domain as your live system?

Comment: @Paddy: Yes, that is correct. We've been thinking if it has to do with us being administrators on our dev machines. Do you have any more insight or ideas? Sounds like you are on to something.

Comment: @Shoban: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - would it be possible to step into the PrincipalContext code and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN which states:

> The **ValidateCredentials** method binds to the server specified in the constructor. If the username and password parameters are null, the credentials specified in the constructor are validated. If no credential were specified in the constructor, and the username and password parameters are null, **this method validates the default credentials for the current principal.**

and together with this information in the documentation of the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298328%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of `PrincipalContext`:

> public PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType contextType, string name):
>   **contextType:** A System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType enumeration value specifying the type of store for the principal context.
>   **name:** The name of the domain or server for System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain context types, the machine name for System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Machine context types, or the name of the server and port hosting the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.ApplicationDirectory instance. **If the name is null for a System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain context type this context is a domain controller for the domain of the user principal under which the thread is running.** If the name is null for a System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Machine context type, this is the local machine name. This parameter cannot be null for System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.ApplicationDirectory context types.

This leads me to conclude that since I don't use the `name` property in the constructor of the `PrincipalContext`, the domain controller will run under my own principal when on my dev machine. This could mean that it uses my users priveliges, which of course are much higher than the machine accounts the production servers are running as. This in turn could make all calls to `Validate` with `null`as password automatically validate due to the higher level of privelige.

At least, this is my theory... Comments and thoughts are welcome, I will be closing this question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is in the code. For a user to be AD authed the password needs to match. A security tokens is generated from AD, and this can't be done without the proper password or impersination (which also requires password).

Is the code using `SELECT user FROM users WHERE password LIKE '%password%'`? I've seen that done before! :(

Comment: Exactly my thought, I can't get my head around the fact that the AD accepts the authentication without it! We rely on AD, no horror-sql. ;-)

Comment: The SQL was just a general thought. ;) Can people log on to AD without a password? If not then I wouldn't waste mutch time investigating AD. First rule of debugging: Always assume the bug is yours. (Read: Not Microsoft)

Comment: No, we are required to use our passwords. Just double checked with the network admin who said there's no option to not use the password and still gain access.

Comment: I added the line of code that seems to be faulty, and it's a call to ValidateCredentials - in PrincipalContext. I agree on the "it's probably me"-approach though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add null validation for password before calling ValidateCredentials? On a side note, client side authentication might help as well.

Comment: That's a good idea, but my question is really about why this happens and not how to get around it. Since it doesn't happen on my production servers I'm not so worried about security, more curious about in which circumstances this will happen. If you have any ideas I'll be glad to hear! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try to

1. handle NULL Parameter Exception.
2. check first both credentials have values.

   ```
   using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
       {
          throw new ArgumentNullException();
          result = null;  // Or redirect to Login Page
       }
       else
       {
           result = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What I am asking is WHY this happens, as I state that it is not a problem for us, just a strange behaviour that I want to understand so I don't create a problem in the future.